# Import module A into module B, but A has already imported module B angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have two modules **User and Product**. User Module has already imported Product Module in order to use the ProductListComponent. Now I want to import/use UserListComponent from User Module in Product Module. But when importing the User Module in Product Module it throws *circular dependency* error. Is there a way to use every module in other module so that my logic always stays in its corresponding module but I can reuse its features?

I was thinking to have a common/Shared Module that imports all other modules in it and that Shared Module is then imported by all the other modules, so this will make all of my modules available to each other. But doing this throws a circular dependency error which is indeed a valid error.

Product Module

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ProductListComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ProductRoutingModule,
  ], exports: [ProductListComponent]
})
export class ProductModule { }
```

User Module

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [UserListComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UserRoutingModule,
    ProductModule
  ], exports: []
})
export class UserModule { }
```

**What I tried with shared module and it looks like**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UserModule,
    ProductModule
  ], exports: []
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Product Module

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ProductListComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ProductRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ], exports: [ProductListComponent]
})
export class ProductModule { }
```

User Module

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [UserListComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UserRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ], exports: []
})
export class UserModule { }
```

Please help me to have a way to share all the modules across all the other modules in the application in order to avoid code repetition or making applications design independent.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, in future, you can use 3x single quotes: ```, to format a block of code using markdown =) Try to use single quote only for single, inline codes.

Comment: For using all modules at app initialization import modules in root/app modules which is not recommended at all but will solve your problem.For optimization refer  my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    you need to register that shared module to app.module like this

    App Module



  @NgModule({
      declarations: [],
      imports: [
        SharedModule
      ], exports: []
    })
    export class AppModule { }

    And shared module should look like this


  @NgModule({
      declarations: [ProductListComponent,UserListComponent],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        UserModule,
        ProductModule
      ], exports: []
    })
    export class SharedModule { }

 Now you can able to use all the modules
 please don't import modules multiple times
```

Answer (score 0):

import the **SharedModule** inside the app module file.

Answer (score 0):

Ahmad, it is **never** suggested/required to import each and every module in shared module.Shared module is there to keep components,directives etc which are required by many modules like **Header(Navbar),footer,sidebar** etc.

In your case ideally you should make a common component/directive if same functionality required at various components(reusability) that component/directive can be kept in shared module and then SharedModule can be imported to FeatureModule (User/Product in your case).

- If functionality not common then only export particular
  component(ProductListComponent) and import that components's
  modules(ProductModule) in required module (UserModule) or vice-versa
  (UserListComponent in ProductModule)

**If every module is imported in each and every module whats the use of using Angular.Moreover, optimization will be heavily effected!**

Comment: Initially I was using only Product List so as you said I imported ProductModule in UserModule as Product List Component was exported but later i got a requirement to use UserList in Product but now importing UserModule in ProductModule is not possible, putting user list and product list in common shared module removes the feature of listing from there corresponding modules and makes me dependent on Shared Module as if i want to use ProductListing of Product Module also having other Components, I will also have to include SharedModule

Comment: In that case it throws 
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src/app/user/user.module.ts -> src/app/product/product.module.ts -> src/app/user/user.module.ts

Comment: import modules in root module instead of importing in cycle in two modules.Circular warning will be thrown because you are  importing user module in product module when product module is already imported in user module.

Comment: Now UserList is not available to ProductModule and vice versa after adding the imports in the AppModule

Comment: have you exported userlistcomponent in usermodule?

Comment: Yes, I've exported the component

Comment: It says app-user-list is not a known element   and same error for app-product-list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201597/discussion-between-ahmad-qureshi-and-varundhariyal).